# How does BitBucket user contributors.txt?

Tags: version-control, bitbucket, checkin

I'm a new BB user, as part of the first 'check in' it asks me to do create a new contributors.txt with my name in it (I'm coming from Github where this wasn't done).

Comment: To list people who contributed to your project?

Comment: why the downvote? This is question to under purpose of a particular file in a software application?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

BitBucket **does not use** `contributors.txt` in any sense (contrary to readme.* on GitHub), just *suggests* to have it